# Retrofit2 requestbody gives error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

On line number 3 It says can not resolve Create, what is wrong with this? This supposed to work.

```
private Uri filePath;
File file = new File(filePath.getPath());
RequestBody rbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
```

Comment: Did you `import okhttp3.RequestBody`? Or some other `RequestBody` class?

Comment: import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;

Comment: Yes It worked, I have to use okhttp3 in this case. I was using okhttp 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It worked, I have to use okhttp3 in this case. I was using okhttp 2